# NFS client (SFU in Windows 7) creates folders with 'x' bits set to false

Tags: windows, permissions, filesystems, nfs

I have a drive mounted on a Windows 7 64-bit machine from a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM via NFS. Whenever I try creating a folder from Windows, the folder is created with its executable bit set to `false`, rendering it non-navigable and non-writable unless I switch to Ubuntu and manually reset folder permissions.

This bars me from creating folders or using any version control software from Windows. Is there any way to enable setting `x` permissions on folders creating via NFS?

*EDIT*: adding info as suggested by [jdebp](https://superuser.com/users/38062/jdebp):

I'm using the MS Services for Unix client to map the NFS drive to `G:`. The output of the `nfsadmin client` command on the client (thus forth known as my host Windows 7 machine) is:

```
Service 'NfsClnt' was not found.
```

I have the server set up on Ubuntu to treat anonymous mounts as `uid=1000` and `gid=1000` (my Ubuntu user's *uid* and *gid*) and the client is configured to have executable flags set in its umask.

When I create a file on the mounted share (either through Eclipse or from Windows Explorer, for instance), the permissions are correctly set:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 klemen klemen    0 2011-07-05 09:46 test.txt
```

But when I create a directory (either from Eclipse, Windows Explorer or from the command line using `mkdir`), the directory is created without its executable flags:

```
drw-rw-r--  2 klemen klemen 4096 2011-07-05 09:42 test
```

My mount options are as follows:

[image: NFS Mount Options]

Comment: Show us in your question the output of `nfsadmin client` on your client machine, and tell us what tool you are using (The POSIX `mkdir` command?  The Win32 `md` command?  Explorer?) to create the directory.

Comment: What is the share's file system?

Comment: The file system on the share is `ext4`.